# Circumference of a circle in Schwarzschild metric in different frames

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Suppose that we want to measure the circumference of a circle of radius $R+h$ around a spherical star of radius $R$. The metric there is the Schwarzschild metric,

$$ds^2=-\big(1-\frac{r_S}{r}\big)dt^2+\frac{dr^2}{\big(1-\frac{r_S}{r}\big)} +r^2d \Omega_2^2,$$

where $d \Omega_2$ is the metric of the 2-sphere.

If an observer traveling along the circle measures the circumference, then the proper distance is

$$dl=\sqrt{\frac{dr^2}{\big(1-\frac{r_S}{r}\big)} +r^2d \Omega_2^2}=r \sin \theta d \phi=2 \pi (R+h),$$

where $\theta=\pi/2$ and $r=R+h$.

What about what an observer situated at $r=\infty$ measures, for the same radius? Is is the same circumference?

Comment: How would an observer at infinity measure that radius?